# How can I count how many times char occur at first String also cccur at second String?

Tags: java, junit

```
   public int count_chars_in_String(String s, String s1){
       int count = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
           if(s.charAt(i) = s1.charAt(i)){

           }
       }
   }
```

This is all I can think about and it was wrong in the if loop. It said that lefthand side must be a variable. How can I do the thing like count the char which appear both at first string also second string?

Comment: You are confusing `=` with `==`. Anyway I can interpret this question in few ways so to make it clearer please [edit] it and include example of input and expected output with explanation of why such output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing an assignment in your `if` statement by using the `=` operator. To compare the two characters use the comparison operator: `==`

Answer (score 1):

'=' operator is assignment.
'==' operator is compraision operator (equality) in most languages.

Comment: Just as an SO FYI, to highlight you use the grave accent located with the tilde key on most keyboards

Answer (score 1):

Use == to compare, also make sure in your code that the lengths of s and s1 are the same (or you use the length of the smallest string as termination) otherwise you will get an:

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

First Understand how this works before implemnting it.. Below code will count the occurenses of second string's char comparing the char of first string's characters. This will not be perfect when first string have same char more than once. Do make modifications for that..

```
public int count_chars_in_String(String s, String s1){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
        for(int j = 0,k = 0; j<s1.length();j++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)){
                k + = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i)+": "+k+" times");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the body of your question (which at this time is flawed) I would count the characters that appear in both of two strings like this:

```
public Set<Character> asSet(String s) {
    Set<Character> in = new HashSet<>();
    // Roll all of the strings characters into the set.
    s.chars().forEach(c -> in.add((char) c));
    return in;
}

public int countCharsInBoth(String s, String s1) {
    // All characters in the first string.
    Set<Character> inBoth = asSet(s);
    // Keep only those in the second string too.
    inBoth.retainAll(asSet(s1));
    // Size of that set is count.
    return inBoth.size();
}

public void test() {
    // Prints 3 as expected.
    System.out.println(countCharsInBoth("Hello", "Hell"));
}
```